# What does an object destructuring pattern used as the rest property of an array destructuring pattern stand for?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) have this example:

> #### Using a binding pattern as the rest property
>
> The rest property of array destructuring assignment can be another array or object binding pattern. This allows you to simultaneously unpack the properties and indices of arrays.
>
> ```js
> const [a, b, ...{ pop, push }] = [1, 2];
> console.log(a, b); // 1 2
> console.log(pop, push); // [Function pop] [Function push]
> ```

What are those `pop` and `push` functions and how to use them?

```js
> pop()
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at pop (<anonymous>)
> push(3)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at push (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: [Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) from arrays

Comment: This is a confusing example because it disassociates the methods from their normal context. In order to use them you need to provide a valid `this` ie using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). For example `let arr = []; push.call(arr, 6);`. This isn't useful, but seems to have been included for illustration of accessing properties of a rest parameter.

Comment: As the quoted text says, they are "*properties and indices of arrays*". (Besides possibly `length`, they're not very useful though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regular destructuring, you can do:

```js
const obj = {a:3, b:4}
const {a} = obj // equivalent to const a = obj.a
```

Now consider the following code:

```js
const [a, b, ...rest] = [1, 2];
console.log(a, b, rest); // 1 2 []
const {push, pop} = rest;
console.log(push, pop);
```

`rest` will be an array containing the third number onwards. Since there is no third number, `rest` will be an empty array.

`push` and `pop` are functions that can be destructured out of an array object. This explains why `const [a, b, ...{ pop, push }] = [1, 2];` will extract the `pop` and `push` functions from the empty array produced by the spread syntax.

Since you don't have a reference to the array created by the spread syntax, these methods aren't very useful in the example you gave. As @pilchard points out, to invoke either of those methods, you will need to use `call` or `apply` so that `this` will be set to a particular array instance.

A more useful example would be to get the count of the other elements in the array (that were not individually destructured):

```js
const [a, b, ...{length}] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(length)
```